# How to Print Multiple Data Types in one statement in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I want to print multiple Data type in one statement but come an error showed in picture. Please help to fixed this problem:

[image]

```
void main(){
int age=21;
String name= "Rubel";
print($name, $age);
//i want to print name and age at a time. can i do this?
```

Comment: Why the dollar signs? `print` only takes a single parameter in Dart. You could do something like `print(name + " " + age.toString());`, or preferably, use string interpolation: `print("$name $age");`.

Comment: Going forward, please don't post screenshots of your errors, code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Answer (score 1):

```
void main(){
  int age=21;
  String name= "Rubel";
  print("$name, $age");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add double quote in `print`

**Code:**

```dart
void main(){
  int age=21;
  String name= "Rubel";
  print("$name, $age");
}
```